# Insights for Page Posts Vs Insights for User news feed/timeline Posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-apps, facebook-insights

Insights for Page Posts Vs Insights for User news feed/timeline Posts:

I am successfully getting insights to all the posts my Facebook developer app is posting to a brand's fan page.

How do I get those insights (total impressions/total reach etc.) for all the posts to a User's news feed/timeline made via my Facebook developer app?
Note: I managed to get only like, comments and shares for these posts.

An early help will be really appreciated here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is no API available for personal profile insights. You can only retrieve the overall app insights or use app events to track certain activities.